# The following classes could not be instantiated custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

I've been giving custom views a try on Android. I got a view built, but when I add the view to my activity XML it gives me this error:

```
The following classes could not be initialized:
    - com.Schnackel.trialapp.RoomView
```

I can remove the error from the custom class design windows if I remove the `<com.Schnackel.trialapp.RoomView` section from the RoomView XML, but the error still shows up in my activity design window. I haven't messed with the RoomView class at all. It has the three initializer methods inlcuding the `public RoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` that I see a couple of questions set as answers. I've tried restarting Android Studio and cleaning the project. The app does build and runs on my device, but when I try to interact with it, it crashes. I've looked through many questions, but can't find one that's helped me solve this issue. Let me know if you need any more info.

here is the stack trace while just editing:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Schnackel.trialapp.R$styleable
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.load(ProjectClassLoader.java:94)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.Schnackel.trialapp.RoomView.init(RoomView.java:50)
at com.Schnackel.trialapp.RoomView.<init>(RoomView.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:375)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:100)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:393)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:337)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:483)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

RoomView XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/RoomColor"
    android:divider="@color/Black">

    <com.Schnackel.trialapp.RoomView
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        app:exampleDimension="24sp"
        app:exampleColor="#33b5e5"
        app:exampleString="Hello, RoomView"
        app:exampleDrawable="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/menu_save"
        android:background="@color/SGreyer"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/roomName"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="@string/menu_save"
        android:background="@color/SGreyer"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/roomArea"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/menu_save"
        android:background="@color/SGreyer"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/roomWatts"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/menu_save"
        android:background="@color/SGreyer"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:id="@+id/roomUsage"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

RoomView Class:

```
package com.Schnackel.trialapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


/**
 * TODO: document your custom view class.
 */
public class RoomView extends View {
    private String mExampleString; // TODO: use a default from R.string...
    private int mExampleColor = Color.RED; // TODO: use a default from R.color...
    private float mExampleDimension = 0; // TODO: use a default from R.dimen...
    private Drawable mExampleDrawable;

    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private float mTextWidth;
    private float mTextHeight;

    public RoomView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public RoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        // Load attributes
        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.RoomView, defStyle, 0);

        mExampleString = a.getString(
                R.styleable.RoomView_exampleString);
        mExampleColor = a.getColor(
                R.styleable.RoomView_exampleColor,
                mExampleColor);
        // Use getDimensionPixelSize or getDimensionPixelOffset when dealing with
        // values that should fall on pixel boundaries.
        mExampleDimension = a.getDimension(
                R.styleable.RoomView_exampleDimension,
                mExampleDimension);

        if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.RoomView_exampleDrawable)) {
            mExampleDrawable = a.getDrawable(
                    R.styleable.RoomView_exampleDrawable);
            mExampleDrawable.setCallback(this);
        }

        a.recycle();

        // Set up a default TextPaint object
        mTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        mTextPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

        // Update TextPaint and text measurements from attributes
        invalidateTextPaintAndMeasurements();
    }

    private void invalidateTextPaintAndMeasurements() {
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(mExampleDimension);
        mTextPaint.setColor(mExampleColor);
        mTextWidth = mTextPaint.measureText(mExampleString);

        Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics = mTextPaint.getFontMetrics();
        mTextHeight = fontMetrics.bottom;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // TODO: consider storing these as member variables to reduce
        // allocations per draw cycle.
        int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
        int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
        int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
        int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();

        int contentWidth = getWidth() - paddingLeft - paddingRight;
        int contentHeight = getHeight() - paddingTop - paddingBottom;

        // Draw the text.
        canvas.drawText(mExampleString,
                paddingLeft + (contentWidth - mTextWidth) / 2,
                paddingTop + (contentHeight + mTextHeight) / 2,
                mTextPaint);

        // Draw the example drawable on top of the text.
        if (mExampleDrawable != null) {
            mExampleDrawable.setBounds(paddingLeft, paddingTop,
                    paddingLeft + contentWidth, paddingTop + contentHeight);
            mExampleDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the example string attribute value.
     * @return The example string attribute value.
     */
    public String getExampleString()
    {
        return mExampleString;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the view's example string attribute value. In the example view, this string
     * is the text to draw.
     * @param exampleString The example string attribute value to use.
     */
    public void setExampleString(String exampleString) {
        mExampleString = exampleString;
        invalidateTextPaintAndMeasurements();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the example color attribute value.
     * @return The example color attribute value.
     */
    public int getExampleColor() {
        return mExampleColor;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the view's example color attribute value. In the example view, this color
     * is the font color.
     * @param exampleColor The example color attribute value to use.
     */
    public void setExampleColor(int exampleColor) {
        mExampleColor = exampleColor;
        invalidateTextPaintAndMeasurements();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the example dimension attribute value.
     * @return The example dimension attribute value.
     */
    public float getExampleDimension() {
        return mExampleDimension;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the view's example dimension attribute value. In the example view, this dimension
     * is the font size.
     * @param exampleDimension The example dimension attribute value to use.
     */
    public void setExampleDimension(float exampleDimension) {
        mExampleDimension = exampleDimension;
       invalidateTextPaintAndMeasurements();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the example drawable attribute value.
     * @return The example drawable attribute value.
     */
    public Drawable getExampleDrawable() {
        return mExampleDrawable;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the view's example drawable attribute value. In the example view, this drawable is
     * drawn above the text.
     * @param exampleDrawable The example drawable attribute value to use.
     */
    public void setExampleDrawable(Drawable exampleDrawable) {
        mExampleDrawable = exampleDrawable;
    }
}
```

P.S. For future reference, should I use android.stackexchange.com for these questions? Is x-posting frowned upon?